# "[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]"

Tags: objective-c

When i run my app it crashes by giving a warning "[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]".can any one help me in correcting this?

Comment: do you have any problem of understanding the meaning of the error message?

Comment: check in your loop `for(int i=0 ;i<=count...` change to `i<count`. Or use `for(... in collection)`

Answer (score 3):

You can find where it is giving this exception just do as suggested in image

[image]

Then run the application, the breakpoint should point you the exact line of code causing exception..

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

You have 10 elements in you array, which are indexed from 0 to 9 and you are trying to get element with index 10, which means 11. element. But you do not have 11 elements in the array

Comment: This is indeed a long way of saying:  index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]     :)

Answer (score -1):

instead you can use following method

```
for(id object in arrHistoricData)
{
    // object returns value in array
}
```